# Sums of non-surjective entire functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two entire, non-surjective, functions. This means

$$
A(z)=e^{f(z)}+c_1
$$
and
$$
  B(z)=e^{g(z)}+c_2
$$
for some entire functions $f$ and $g$, and some complex constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

When is the sum $A(z)+B(z)$ an surjective entire function? More precisely, is there any condition on $f$ and $g$? Clearly the sum may fail to be surjective, for example when $f(z)=g(z)+c$. But also can be surjective, for example when $f(z)=2g(z)$. A naive conjecture would be that the sum is surjective as long as $f-g$ is not constant. Is that actually true?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sum is surjective, with some trivial exceptions. Here is
a general Theorem of Emile Borel: Let $g_j$ be entire, and
$$e^{g_1}+\ldots+e^{g_n}=0.$$
Then the set of indices $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ can be partitioned
into disjoint subsets $I_k$, such that for $i,j\in I_k$ we have $g_i-g_j$ is constant, and
$$\sum_{j\in I_k}e^{g_j}=0,$$
for every $k$.

In your case, suppose that the sum of two $e^{g_j}+c_j$ is not surjective, then we have a relation of the form
$$e^{g_1}+e^{g_2}+e^{g_3}=0,$$
or of the form
$$e^{g_1}+e^{g_2}+e^{g_3}+e^c=0.$$
Applying Borel's theorem, we conclude in the first case that
$g_i=g+c_i,$ $1\leq i\leq 3$, $\sum_{i=1}^3 e^{c_i}=0$.
And in the second case, one of the $g_i$ must be constant,
for example, $g_3=-c$ and if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are not constants then their difference must be constant, namely  $g_1=g_2=\pi i(2n+1)$.

A good reference for Borel's theorem is the book

Serge Lang, Introduction to complex hyperbolic spaces,
Springer, 1987.